# Loading collection of String into model from persistent object with hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When try to place a list of stings taken from an object I've loading in from a database via hibernate I'm getting this exception.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

The method I've used to load the list is within a transaction. But when I try to place the list in the model I get the above exception. I'm taking from this that hibernate is requiring me to have even this line of code within a transaction also. But given that it's not a database operation why is this so?

```
@RequestMapping(value="{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addComment(@PathVariable String id, Model model, String comment) {
    personService.addComment(Long.parseLong(id), comment);
    Person person = personService.getPersonById(Long.parseLong(id));
    model.addAttribute(person);
    List<String> comments = personService.getComments(id);
    model.addAttribute(comments);
    return "/Review";
}
```

Service object.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

private Workaround personDAO;


public PersonServiceImpl() {
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public void savePerson(Person person) { 
    personDAO.savePerson(person);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public Person getPersonById(long id) {
    return personDAO.getPersonById(id);
}

@Autowired
public void setPersonDAO(Workaround personDAO) {
    this.personDAO = personDAO;
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
    return personDAO.getAllPeople();
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public void addComment(Long id, String comment) {
    Person person = getPersonById(id);
    person.addComment(comment);
    savePerson(person);
}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false)
public List<String> getComments(String id) {
    return personDAO.getComments(Long.parseLong(id));
}
```

}

DAO

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;



@Repository
public class PersonDAO implements Workaround {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public PersonDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;   
}

private Session currentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public void addPerson(Person person) {
    currentSession().save(person);
}

public Person getPersonById(long id) {
    return (Person) currentSession().get(Person.class, id);
}


public void savePerson(Person person) {
    currentSession().save(person);
}

public List<Person> getAllPeople() {
    List<Person> people = currentSession().createQuery("from Person").list();
    return people;

}

public List<String> getComments(long id) {
    return getPersonById(id).getComments();
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post the spring configuration file where you setup the persistence. I think the problem is in your config, not in the code (because the code looks fine). And please post the Person class and the complete stack trace with some hints about the line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am relatively new to Hibernate but I'll take a guess at this from my understanding of it.

By default `@OneToMany` collections are lazily loaded.  So when you load your Person object a proxy will be created in place of your actual `comments` list.  This list won't be loaded until you call the getter for that list (ie `getComments()`) as you are, and even then I don't think the full list is loaded at once, more so one by one (yep multiple db calls) as you iterate through the list or the whole list at one if you call .size().

However, I think the catch here is that you must load the list within the same session that you load the parent (`Person`) object.  When you are loading the `Person` object you have a reference to the current session and then once you call the `getComments()` on that Person object the session is closed.

I think to keep the whole process in one session you could manually open and close your session like so in your DAO class.

```
public List<String> getComments(long id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    List<String> comments = getPersonById(id).getComments();

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.close();

    return comments;
}
```

Setting the FetchType to EAGER would solve the problem, but from what I have read it is generally not recommended unless you always need the comments loaded with the Person object.

Comment: This was the right idea. However, there's a Hibernate static method for initializing collections Hibernate.initialize(). I just used this method in my DAO method that gets the collection and now everything's gravy.

Comment: Great thanks for posting that, I didn't know about Hibernate.initialize() so that sounds much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Change a fetch type to `FetchType.EAGER`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're using

```
currentSession()
```

Try to replace it with

```
private Session currentSession() {
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

bcause the exception says that there isn't any open session.

Comment: according to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight  `getCurrentSession` is right

Answer (score 0):

You should review the `Person` class mapping, maybe the `Comments` field is mapped with the `LAZY` attribute and so it's not loaded in the DAO. When you call the `getComments` method Hibernate tries to load the attribute from the database but at that time there is no session, hence the exception. To solve this issue change the mapping attribute to `EAGER`.